# Heptagon, nonagon

Tags: mathematics, geometry

What is the trick to constructing a heptagon and a nonagon which have all their sides equal? The length of the side has to be a natural number. Your answer should include a drawing of the two polygons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick is

> to not make the angles equal.
>
>  The shapes below are a heptagon and a nonagon with equal sides, and both are very easy to construct (since they're just made up of a square grid, plus some equilateral triangles built off of it).
>
>  [image]

Comment: I had in mind  convex polygons. Can you make them convex?

Comment: This answer is a valid method of answering the problem as stated; that it fits perfectly but isn't what you were thinking of is a fault of the puzzle and not the answer.

Comment: @VassilisParassidis Sure - at every concave angle ABC, draw circles of radius 1 around A and C. They intersect at B, as well as some other point, which we'll call D. Then you can "pop out" that angle by replacing A-B-C with A-D-C. Repeat until all convex angles are popped out.